# Spring Auth Server with Federated Social Login and Postman

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I have a number of Resource Servers secured behind a Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring Auth Server 1.1 using the sample configuration for Federated logins. For testing purposes, I am developing with Google's OIDC. My Spring Cloud Gateway is configured as my OAuth Client.

I have Federated logins working properly (presenting the user with a Google Login Screen) when making a GET request from a browser. However, when I try to configure PostMan to get an Access Token using OAuth2 authentication and requesting an Access Code, I keep getting an "invalid_grant" error from within Postman after I enter my Google credentials.

Within SAS I have the following setup for the oath2 setup:

```
security:
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          client-1:
            registration:
              client-id: "google"
              # the client secret is "secret" (without quotes)
              client-secret: "{bcrypt}$2a$10$jdJGhzsiIqYFpjJiYWMl/eKDOd8vdyQis2aynmFN0dgJ53XvpzzwC"
              client-authentication-methods: "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types: "client_credentials,authorization_code,refresh_token,id_token"

              redirect-uris: "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google" #this is the Spring Cloud Gateway
              scopes: "profile,openid"
              require-authorization-consent: false
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            provider: google
            client-id: POPULATED_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
            client-secret: POPULATED_CLIENT_SECRET
            scope: openid, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
            client-name: Sign in with Google          
        provider:
          google:
            user-name-attribute: email
```

Within my Postman setup, I am using the following variables:

```
AUTH_CALLBACK_URL: http://localhost:8094/login/oauth2/code/google #SAS runs on port 8094
AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET: secret
AUTH_CLIENT_ID: google
AUTH_URL: http://localhost:8094/oauth2/authorize
AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL: http://localhost:8094/oauth2/token
AUTH_SCOPE: openid profile
```

Postman seems to be working correctly until the **Collecting Access Token ** step. At that point in the console it always returns `Error: invalid_grant`

In the SAS logs I see the following:

```
2023-08-31 15:57:24,589 TRACE [http-nio-8094-exec-8] o.s.s.o.s.a.w.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter: Client authentication failed: [invalid_grant] Client authentication failed: code
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: Client authentication failed: code
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.CodeVerifierAuthenticator.throwInvalidGrant(CodeVerifierAuthenticator.java:156)
```

I know using Federated login for this use case could be overkill, but we are trying to consolidate all OIDC providers in a single place (including local login) and SAS ***seems*** to support this. If this is not the best use of SAS and KeyCloak may be a better fit, we would be open to that as a last resort.

I expected Postman to provide a valid access token that could then be used as Authorization for API Requests to the secured resource servers.

Comment: what have you set as `Client Authentication` in Postman `Authorization` tab?

Comment: Send as Basic Auth Header

Answer (score 0):

**Requests to the gateway are authorized with session cookies**, not access tokens (as for any request to an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`).

**Direct requests to your resource servers are authorized with access tokens delivered by your authorization server**, not Google ones (which are used just for exchanges between your authorization server and Google one during "social login").

Knowing that, you need different Postman configurations if you query the gateway or one of your resource servers directly.

You might find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNDSEZF5IpA) useful to learn how to intercept Chrome cookies in Postman.

To query the gateway, you'll:

- authenticate on your gateway with Chrome (with the usual `authorization_code` flow configured with your `google` registration, redirecting to your authorization server, which in turn redirects to Google one)
- retrieve the cookie of the authorized session in Postman
- send Postman requests with the cookie for the authorized session on the gateway

When skipping the gateway and querying one of the resource servers directly, use the standard Postman OAuth2 client features in the authorization tab of your collection or query, but be sure to point it to your authorization server (not Google one directly). And as you set `client-authentication-methods: "client_secret_basic"`, also double check that you have set `Client Authentication` to `Send as Basic Auth header` in Postman `Authorization` tab.

Comment: This is useful information, thank you. Is there really no way to setup Postman to do this using its OAuth2 authorization flow?

Comment: You mean send a token in an Authorization header to an application expecting a session cookie?

Comment: I mean a way to setup Postman to run a number of tests against a secured Spring Cloud Gateway using the provided OAuth2 authentication within Postman without requiring a Chrome extension. I would expect Postman to be able to act as an OAuth2 client to then authenticate against the Gateway. I must have a misunderstanding of the role the Cloud Gateway is playing in this setup. I have no issue using the extension, but I just assumed it was possible totally within Postman.

Comment: You have to understand and accept that OAuth2 starts on the OAuth2 client. Requests are not OAuth2 between your front-end(s) and the Gateway. I think my answer is pretty clear on the fact that **you have to query the resource servers directly if you want to use Postman OAuth2 client features**.

Comment: If I want to query the resource servers directly, I am still unable to get a token using Postman. What is the best process to get a Federated Token from SAS using Postman?